# Using multiples datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use multiple datepickers in the same form
and need altFields as well as certain logics for each of these datepickers.
The datepickers are named dynamically such as `date_1`, `date_2` etc.
whereas the altFields are named `date_1_alt`, `date_2_alt`.

I don´t want to setup multiple definitions `foreach datepicker`, but just use one single definition by selector `[id^='date_']` or i.e. by class `.date`

```
$("[id^='date_']").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
  altFormat:  "yy-mm-dd",
  altField: $(this).attr('id')+"_alt"
});
```

The problem is the dynamic definition of the altField (the code given does not work).
I have tried many different ways but couldn't find the right way to define a dynamic assignment that would automatically create the corresponding altFields (such `date_1` -> `date_1_alt` etc.)

Does anyone know the right way to get this done?
The same issue is relevant to further logic, such as defining the `onSelect` functions etc.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can manually iterate over each matching element and apply datepicker that way:

```
$("[id^='date_']").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        altFormat:  "yy-mm-dd",
        altField: $this.attr('id')+"_alt"
    });
});
```